# Resolve 'typedef redefinition with different types ('struct max_align_t' vs 'struct max_align_t')'

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I've been using Qt 5.15.2 and switching between WebAssembly and Desktop 32-bit in QtCreator for my project. When I switched back to WebAssembly I received the error:

In included file: typedef redefinition with different types ('struct max_align_t' vs 'struct max_align_t')

On my first line:

"#include <QGuiApplication>"
This error is persisting now on all WebAssembly projects I create and I even attempted uninstalling and reinstalling Qt

Answer (score 0):

try remove file *.pro.user and load project